# display ID field MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4 how do I display the ID field from a DB. I dont want to edit the field as you cant but just display it with the other fields?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Comment: whats wrong with item.ID ? did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the same way you have done for Title and Genre

```
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
```

Go through this Tutorial to help you understand MVC

[MVC 4 Music Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (although there are multiple ways to do this):

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID)
```